# Run script before unit tests

Tags: gradle, groovy

For my for Android app's unit and instrumented tests, I need certain files to exist on disk.  I've created a Python script which generates them.  However, I'm having trouble modifying my app's build.gradle file to run the script before my tests.  Based on some examples I saw, I tried

```
task generateFile(type: Exec) {
    onlyIf { !file('app/src/test/resources/needed_file').exists() }
    commandLine 'python3', 'scripts/generate_test_files.py'
}

testDebugUnitTest.dependsOn generateFile
```

However, I get the error

> Could not get unknown property 'testDebugUnitTest' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

I've tried several variations such as `test.dependsOn generateFile` but all of them give similar errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wildly guessing that `testDebugUnitTest` task is generated later in some `afterEvaluate` action or similar, try to be a bit more reactive. If the guess is right, this should help:

```
tasks
    .matching { it.name == "testDebugUnitTest" }
    .configureEach { dependsOn(generateFile) }
```